# C++ if statement is not testing correctly

Tags: c++, if-statement, console, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a game of tic tac toe and it works to the extent of i can insert Xs but the computer can only insert one O. Since this is a game of tic tac toe i need the computer to be able to insert more than one zero. Every time this code is ran if there is already a variable with the value o it will not change another variable to the value o. I think the problem is an if statement. Sorry for not clearly stating my question. If it still does not make sense you can compile the rest of my code. Then you might see what i meen.

Here's [the rest](http://troop-89.org/code.html)

Here is what I believe to be the problem.

```
bool j=true ;
int lo=0;
string hi [9]={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
while(j==true)
{
  if (lo>8)
  {
    j=false;
  }
  else if(hi[lo]!="x"&&hi[lo]!="o")
  {
    hi[lo]="o";
    j=false;
  }
  else
  {
    lo=lo+1;
    j=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Your code is specifically written to insert one "o" and exit (sets `j` to `false` straight away). What is the problem then? What is "if statement is not testing correctly" supposed to mean?

Comment: the code works the first time, but when there is a o already stored in one of the values it does not enter a second o. That is why i am saying it is not testing correctly.

Comment: seriously I don't mind that this gets down voted but the least you could do be for down voting is compile the code from the link and see what i mean for yourself.

Comment: @user1108980 But the code does what it looks like it does: put a single "o" in the array at the first position where it doesn't have an "o" or an "x". Why do you think it would do something else? In all probability, the error is somewhere else, like in the code that copies the string array back to the individual strings.

Answer (score 4):

If I can re-write your code:

```
for (lo = 0; lo < 9; lo++){
  if (hi[lo] == " "){
    hi[lo] = "o";
    break;
  }
}
```

So you're right, it inserts one "o".

What's the question?

EDIT: Since you are trying to write a tic-tac-toe game, let me suggest some overall pseudo-code:

```
repeat
  ask user where they want to place an "x" (i.e. get a number from 0 to 8)
  if that square is not blank, say so and ask again
  else put the "x" in the square
  If this completes a row, column, or diagonal, exit saying "You win!"
-> enter the loop here if you are making the first move
  then find out where to put an "o". You do this by looking at all unoccupied squares.
  for each unoccupied square
    look at the row, column, and diagonal it is on
    if putting an "o" there would make you the winner, give it a really high score
    if putting an "o" there would block the user from winning, give it a high score
    if putting an "o" there would mean that you could win on the following move, give it a medium score
    Otherwise give it a score that is the number of rows, columns, and diagonals it could possibly tie up
    end for each
  Then put the "o" on the highest-scored square (or one of the highest-scored squares if there are more than one)
  If you completed a row, column, or diagonal, exit saying "I win!".
  If you can't find a square to mark, exit saying "I give up".
end repeat
```

I'm sure there is a shorter version than this.
It's just off the top of my head.

Comment: ya sorry for the messy code that is how I first wrote it. Then I got stumped so I tried rewriting it a few other ways.